# Automatically add newline at end of curl response body as default setting

Tags: curl, dotfiles

Can you configure curl with a dotfile to automatically print responses with the `-w '\n'` flag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation at https://www.mit.edu/afs.new/sipb/user/ssen/src/curl-7.11.1/docs/curl.html, it is stated, that there is in fact a `.curlrc` (or `_curlrc` on windows - but I'll assume you're on linux).

So, in order to do what you want, create a file `~/.curlrc`and add the following line: `-w '\n'`. That's  it.

See https://curl.se/docs/manual.html for more examples.